# Jenkins job for artifactory maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am configuring a Jenkins build which can build and release artifacts to artifactory. I have installed m3 artifcactory and added repo URL but not sure what steps I need to add more and do I need to make changes in POM.xml as well. Can someone please guide me on this?

Comment: show us what you've tried or reasearched

Comment: Well your configuration can be inserted into the POM or the settings.xml of your Maven. To deploy you artifacts you have to configure a distribution management.

Comment: @Edwi so far I have created build job in jenkins and added maven artifactory plugin. In my pom.xml,  I have added repository details for snapshots and release.  I did "mvn clean install -DskipTests=true" and jenkins build is successful with log : "Installing /opt/jenkins-slave/workspace/.../.../xyz/target/xyz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/xyz/xyz/test/xyz/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/abc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar". In jenkins build, I see "artifactory build info, artifactory release promotion etc". Now need to setup deploy/release for snapshot to Artifactory and not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your comment that you have successfully installed your artifact to your local repository. Next you need to deploy the artifact to your remote repository. This is usually accomplished using the maven deploy plugin, documented here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

Note that you will need to add a distributionManagement section to your pom. If your repository is secured, which it most likely is, you will need to add your credentials to your settings.xml in the server section. For this server section, you will need a username and password for your repository that has the appropriate upload privileges. Your admin account should already have this privilege so you can use admin for your username if you like.

Have your Jenkins job execute "mvn clean deploy -DskipTests".

Comment: Getting this error while executing mvn deploy :  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project myProject: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.test:myProject:jar:1.0.0-20180510.062919-1 from/to my-snapshots (http://repository.intranet/abc-snapshots): Failed to transfer file: http://repository.intranet.abc.com/artifactory/abc-snapshots/com/test/myProject/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/myProject-1.0.0-20180510.062919-1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your credentials. Have you put your credentials in the settings.xml and checked if that user has upload privileges?

Comment: thanks for help. Issue was with settings.xml credentials.

Comment: Now I am facing issue in release stage. When doing Artifactory release staging, I am getting below error : **[RELEASE] Changing POMs to release version
[RELEASE] ERROR: Snapshot detected in file '/opt/jenkins-slave/workspace/..../pom.xml': com.xyz:abc-mydependecy:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10.**   !!!!               abc-mydependecy:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is a dependency module in my pom.xml. Could you please suggest why this error comes and how to fix this?